# Resizing ggbiplot plots

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I am looking for ways to reconfigure ggbiplot plots to match each other. I know that plots are scaled differently to 'fit' the data behind the plot but I wondered if anyone has any advice on how to make plots match.

I used ggarange to make this mutliplot output:

```
ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,
          labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

As an example one of the ggbiplots code is here:

```
p2 <- ggbiplot(colour30.pca,ellipse=TRUE, groups = colour30$Trait.Feed.Mech., 
               obs.scale = 2, var.scale = 1, labels.size = 4, varname.size = 5)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
      guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3)) +
      scale_colour_npg(name="Feeding Mode (>30 Obs.)") +
      xlab ("PC1 (37.4%)")+ 
      ylab ("PC2 (18.0%)")
```

Below is the output that I would like to neaten up if possible

[output plot I would like to neaten up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gyUW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- The `patchwork` package can be used e.g. to align the axes all plots within a particular row or column
- Sometimes, the aspect ratio of a plot is fixed with `coord_fixed` so they do not fill up all the space
- Legends can be combines (e.g. `patchwork::wrap_plots(guides = "collect")`)
- Apply the same theme to all plots to unify font sizes etc.